# How to transform an item in Qt Quick UI forms?

Tags: qt, qml

Qt Quick UI forms does not support some features like Transform, Translate, Functions etc
But how to overcome from this problem and please suggest any solutions to this
I need to translate an item in Qt Quick UI form how can i?

Comment: What is _Qt Quick UI forms_? What is your _real_ target? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` property which all items have.

```
 Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "red"
        transform: Translate { y: -20 }
    }
```

`transform` can be any of Rotation, Translation and Scale. Check here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transform.html